# Need a bit of guidance in mathematical morphology operation "dilation" code in R

Tags: arrays, r, image, mathematical-morphology

I am trying to apply a mathematical morphology operation on a binary image. The operation am trying to apply is dilation. I am posting the code below.

```
# Dilation of A with a square with size a. The reference is (1,1)
#

mm_dilationsqr <- function(A,a){

    C <- A

    if(a<=1) return(C)

    for(i in 1:a)
    for(j in 1:a)
    {
        B <- mm_translation(A,1-i,1-j)
        C <- mm_union(C,B)

    }

    C <- mm_translation(C,a/2,a/2)

    return(C)
}
```

The above is a dilation function which calls translation and union functions too which are posted below.

```
    # Translation of set A by x,y. 
# Warning: no periodicity, watch the borders!
#

mm_translation <- function(A,x,y){

    C <- mm_zero()

    if((x>=-M+1) & (x<=M) & (y>=-N+1) & (y<=N))
    {
        for(i in 1:M)
          for(j in 1:N)
          {
            if((i+x>=0) & (i+x<=M) & (j+y>=0) & (j+y<=N))
            C[i+x,j+y] <- A[i,j]
          }

    }

    return(C)
}
```

Union function below:

```
# Union (OR) of sets A and B
#

mm_union <- function(A,B){
    C<-as.integer(A|B)
    dim(C) <- c(M,N)
    return(C)
}
```

Now when am trying to process the image in array form using mm_dilation function, I am getting this error: `Error in mm_union(C, B) : binary operation on non-conformable arrays`.
My array dimensions are

```
dim(TA)
[1] 745 691
```

When am using a subset of the above given TA array of dimension given below, the code is working in that case.

```
dim(A)
[1] 21 21
```

So I want to know how I can improve this so that it can process image of `TA` dimensions.